# Getting Bluetooth LMP version via Powershell

Tags: powershell, winapi

I have taken a look at **CIM_NetworkAdapter**, **Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty** **CIM_LogicalDevice**, **Win32_PnPDevice** and more.

How can I go about grabbing the LMP version of a Bluetooth adapter from its "Bluetooth Radio Information" in its advanced properties?
Is this possible in Regedit -or any other way?

**EDIT,**
**ANSWER:**
Here's a modified version of an answer I received on Reddit from u/ChaosTheoryRules

```
$BTDevices = Get-PnpDevice -Class "Bluetooth"
Foreach ($device in $BTDevices) {
    $BTDeviceProperty = Get-PnpDeviceProperty -KeyName "DEVPKEY_Bluetooth_RadioLmpVersion" -InstanceId $device.InstanceID
    If ($BTDeviceProperty -And $BtDeviceProperty.Data) {
        $bluetoothVersion = Switch ($BTDeviceProperty.Data) {
            0 { '1.0b' }
            1 { '1.1' }
            2 { '1.2' }
            3 { '2.0 + EDR' }
            4 { '2.1 + EDR' }
            5 { '3.0 + HS' }
            6 { '4.0' }
            7 { '4.1' }
            8 { '4.2' }
            9 { '5.0'}
            10 { '5.1' }
            11 { '5.2' }
            default { "UKNOWN" }
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $bluetoothVersion
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/vmexhm/getting_bluetooth_lmp_version_via_powershell/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the equipment to test, so I can only provide some reference documentation.
You can use [BluetoothGetRadioInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothgetradioinfo) and the structure [BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/ns-bluetoothapis-bluetooth_radio_info)   to get relevant information `lmpSubversion`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
 
#pragma comment(lib,"Bthprops.lib")
 
using namespace std;
 
int main(void)
{
    wcout.imbue(locale(""));
    HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND hbf = NULL;
    HANDLE hbr = NULL;
    HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND hbdf = NULL;
    BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS btfrp = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS) };
    BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO bri = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO)};
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS btsp = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS) };
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btdi = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO) };
    hbf=BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&btfrp, &hbr);
    bool brfind = hbf != NULL;
    while (brfind)
    {
        if (BluetoothGetRadioInfo(hbr, &bri) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << "Class of device: 0x" << uppercase << hex << bri.ulClassofDevice << endl;
            wcout <<"Name:"<< bri.szName << endl;
            cout <<"Manufacture:0x"<< uppercase << hex << bri.manufacturer << endl;
            cout << "Subversion:0x" << uppercase << hex << bri.lmpSubversion << endl;
            //
            btsp.hRadio = hbr;
            btsp.fReturnAuthenticated = TRUE;
            btsp.fReturnConnected = FALSE;
            btsp.fReturnRemembered = TRUE;
            btsp.fReturnUnknown = TRUE;
            btsp.cTimeoutMultiplier = 30;
            hbdf=BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&btsp, &btdi);
            bool bfind = hbdf != NULL;
            while (bfind)
            {
                wcout << "[Name]:" << btdi.szName;
                cout << ",[Address]:0x" << uppercase << hex << btdi.Address.ullLong << endl;
                bfind=BluetoothFindNextDevice(hbdf, &btdi);
            }
            BluetoothFindDeviceClose(hbdf);
        }
        CloseHandle(hbr);
        brfind=BluetoothFindNextRadio(hbf, &hbr);
    }
    BluetoothFindRadioClose(hbf);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```